# How to limit the area in QGraphicsScene where a custom QGraphicsItem can be moved?

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a QGraphicsScene where I have QGraphicsItems. These items are movable and I can move them all over the QGraphicsScene but I would like to limit the area where these items can be moved. The sizes of the QGraphicsScene don't have to change. I would really appreciate if someone gave me an example of how to do it in python.

Here's what I have now

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QPointF
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, \
    QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPolygonItem, QApplication
from PySide2.QtGui import QPen, QColor, QBrush, QPolygonF


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1000, 800)
        self.layout_ = QVBoxLayout()
        self.view_ = GraphicsView()

        self.layout_.addWidget(self.view_)
        self.setLayout(self.layout_)

class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.scene_ = QGraphicsScene()
        self.polygon_creation = self.PolyCreation()

        self.scene_.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
        self.setScene(self.scene_)

        self.polyCreator()

    def polyCreator(self):
        self.polygon_creation.poly()
        polygon = self.polygon_creation.polygon()
        new_poly = self.scene().addPolygon(polygon)
        new_poly.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("gray")))
        new_poly.setPen(QPen(QColor("gray")))
        new_poly.setFlag(QGraphicsPolygonItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        new_poly.setFlag(QGraphicsPolygonItem.ItemIsMovable)
        new_poly.setFlag(QGraphicsPolygonItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        new_poly.setPos(0, 0)

    class PolyCreation(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

        def poly(self):
            self.poly_points = (QPointF(0, 0),
                                      QPointF(0, 50),
                                      QPointF(50, 50),
                                      QPointF(50, 0))

            self.shape = QPolygonF(self.poly_points)
            self.setPolygon(self.shape)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Test()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I've also found an answer in cpp, but I can't understand it very well, so if someone could "translate" it in python that'd be great too.
Here's the link [restrict movable area of qgraphicsitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548254/restrict-movable-area-of-qgraphicsitem) (Please check @Robert's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is to restrict the new position *before* it's finally applied.

To achieve so, you need to also set the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag and check for `ItemPositionChange` changes, then compare the item bounding rect with that of the scene, and eventually return a different position after correcting it.

```py
class PolyCreation(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(QPolygonF([
            QPointF(0, 0),
            QPointF(0, 50),
            QPointF(50, 50),
            QPointF(50, 0)
        ]))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("gray")))
        self.setPen(QPen(QColor("blue")))
        self.setFlags(
            self.ItemIsSelectable
            | self.ItemIsMovable
            | self.ItemIsFocusable
            | self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
        )
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemPositionChange and self.scene():
            br = self.polygon().boundingRect().translated(value)
            sceneRect = self.scene().sceneRect()
            if not sceneRect.contains(br):
                if br.right() > sceneRect.right():
                    br.moveRight(sceneRect.right())
                if br.x() < sceneRect.x():
                    br.moveLeft(sceneRect.x())
                if br.bottom() > sceneRect.bottom():
                    br.moveBottom(sceneRect.bottom())
                if br.y() < sceneRect.y():
                    br.moveTop(sceneRect.top())
                return br.topLeft()
        return super().itemChange(change, value)


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.scene_ = QGraphicsScene()

        self.scene_.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
        self.setScene(self.scene_)
        self.scene_.addItem(PolyCreation())
```

Notes:

- the above code will obviously only work properly for top level items (not children of other items);
- it will work as long as the item doesn't have *any* transformation applied (rotation, scale, etc.); if you want to support that, you have to consider the [`sceneTransform()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#sceneTransform) to get the actual bounding rect of the polygon;
- it doesn't consider the pen width, so if the item has a *thick* pen, the resulting polygon may go *beyond* the scene boundaries; to avoid that, use the actual `boundingRect()` of the item and *adjust* it by using *half* the pen width;
- avoid nested classes, they are rarely required and they only tend to make code unnecessarily convoluted;
- you were not actually using that subclass, since you're in fact adding *another* polygon item based on the polygon of that instance;
- all items are always positioned at `(0, 0)` by default, specifying it again is pointless;
- [`shape()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) is an existing (and quite important) function of all items, you shall not overwrite it;